# What is the cleanest method to determine if a string has a value?

Tags: c#, string

I want to know if a string has any non-whitespace characters in it -- so if it's *not* null or just full of spaces or tabs.  I'm tired of doing this:

```
if(!String.IsNullOrWhitespace(something))
```

There is nothing wrong with this, it's just verbose.

This works (since a string is simply an array of Chars)...

```
something.Any()
```

...but it breaks if the variable is NULL (and it wouldn't account for whitespace).

I know I can write an extension method for this, but I feel like there should be something in the core C# library that I'm just missing.

Comment: you could write a snippet. Seriously, what's wrong with the first line? Semantically its very clear. Sure, it has a lot of characters, but so do manyy English words/phrases.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with it, it's just verbose.

Comment: String.IsNullOrEmpty...

Comment: You already have the answer

Comment: Your description looks more like `IsNullOrEmpty` than `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`...

Answer (score 3):

You're not missing anything. My recommendation is an extension method:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool HasValue(this string value)
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
if (myString.HasValue()) ...
```

Comment: Which will be very confusing anywhere else, as a string composed only of whitespace still has a value (and might be a valid value for ... something).

Comment: @Deduplicator hah, hadn't considered that. Perhaps a better name is in order. That or have it use `IsNullOrEmpty`. I'll update the example.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use String.IsNullOrEmpty? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Now if we knew which part of his problem description is right, and which is wrong, we would know if this is a good answer. Or the other one. Or neither.

Comment: Yes I guess you are right.  So let's all move along to the next question.